# Local DNS Forward Lookup Zone has out-dated Host (A) records

Tags: networking, dns, ip

I am running into an issue in my local DNS where my forward lookup zone is resolving PC names to incorrect IP addresses.

I am somewhat of a beginner in DNS and active directory, but from I have been reading it seems that for the forward lookup zone to update the IP addresses of the host records I would need to implement a reverse lookup zone for that subnet and configure dynamic updates of records. Does that sound correct?

I know I can simply update the DNS entry in the forward lookup zone with the correct IP, but could anyone elaborate on what would happen if I deleted the record for that PC in DNS? Would the record re-establish with up-to-date information? Or would that PC be on an island not able to talk to the network until someone added the record back manually?

Thanks in advance for all help and info!

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Windows Server? If so, what version? And how is the server configured, Domain Controller, DNS, etc. Do you have DHCP enabled on the server or are you using your router for DHCP? Does this issue happen with all clients or just some?

Comment: Yes configured as a domain controller, DHCP server, and DNS using windows server 2019. I have seen the issue happen only for some clients, but I am not sure what specifically goes out to update the DNS records in the forward lookup zone or how often. 

I see some clients have more recent timestamps and some are as old as 3-4 years + old.

Comment: Does your DNS server's Event Log say anything regarding DNS updates (and are those even enabled in zone settings)?

Comment: The zone has dynamic updates enabled for "secure only". I'm not familiar with how to view and analyze the logs for DNS though... I'm sorry.